# Azure AD SAML Federation with multiple Return URLs

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I am working on an application that is using Azure AD as an IDP, and though I have the full integration implemented successfully, I can't seem to use the same AD Application from multiple environments.

To elaborate, I generate a SAML request following the guidelines documented at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-single-sign-on-protocol-reference

Per the documentation, I should be able to specify a URI for the *AssertionConsumerServiceUrl* parameter, and as long as the URI is in the AD App configured Return URLs, it should redirect to that specific destination.

Through my testing, it seems that attribute is being ignored entirely. I know this because I used a value that is not even on the Return URL list, and I received no error, the redirect happened to whichever the top-most registered URL is.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't used SAML myself with Azure AD. The docs do say though that "this must match *the RedirectUri* of the cloud service". An indication it expects only one?

Comment: @juunas, thanks for the response... it does seem to imply it, but the fact that it allows multiple URIs on the admin side, as well as the fact that it doesn't error out when providing a URI that is not on the list, leads me to believe it's being ignored.